# How to pass parameterized newVersion argument to the set goal of Versions Maven Plugin?

Tags: java, maven

Since maven 3.2.1 it is possible to safely (i.e. without warnings) [use property expressions in versions](http://maven.apache.org/docs/3.2.1/release-notes.html) such as **${revision}**, **${changelist}** and **${sha1}**.

Now, the problem is that I'd like to update my multi-module project's version to something like **1.0-${revision}** using the set goal of the Versions Maven Plugin, but after running it I end up with version **1.0-null** instead of **1.0-${revision}**. The exact Maven command i use is shown below:

```
mvn versions:set -DnewVersion=0.1-${revision}
```

I tried escaping **$**, **{** and **}** special characters in newVersion, but to no avail.

I could go with updating the version of each module separately, but it's a tedious thing to do.

Any help will be appreciated.

Comment: Have you tried to quote `0.1-${revision}` like the following `0.1-\${revision}` to prevent expanding by the shell...

Comment: Yup. I have also tried 0.1-$\{revision\} as shown in [this blog](http://www.tikalk.com/devops/thats-one-small-step-maven-giant-leap-continuous-delivery/) entry.

Answer (score 0):

So, what finally worked for me was running set goal of Versions Maven Plugin **without** any arguments, like below:

```
mvn versions:set
```

During the execution I was asked to provide new version for my project and so I typed **0.1-${revision}** without escaping any characters and the new version was correctly set to the provided value.